# Download and install Android System Images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Can I download Android system images outside android studio using the link in screenshoot.
If yes How to Install it ?

The download process is blocker I cannot put it in background, and I have a poor Internet connection.

[image]

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to download system images and other packages without Android Studio.

Just use command-line tool: [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

To download Android R image with Google Api for x86 architecture just use:

```
sdkmanager --channel=0 "system-images;android-R;google_apis;x86"
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install it manualy, I found that it is possible to download the system images from direct link and extract it into sdk folder.

[image]

And this works for me on `API 29`

direct link used `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-29_r10.zip`

Comment: I did that, but AndroidStudio does not recognize the provided image. It keeps on insisting to download the image, which it says cannot be found. It seems that Jetbrains keeps an own repository. How can I "register" a provided image with the IDE?